# Save image from url to special folder

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to save images from url to special folder, for example 'my_images', but not to default(where my *.py file is). Is it possible to make it?
Because my code saves all images to folder with *.py file.
Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os

BASE_URL = 'https://fachowiec.com/sklep/pl/products/index?Products_page=1&pageSize=15'
def get_domain(url):
    domain = re.findall(r'https:\W\W\w+\.\w+', url)
    return domain[0]


def get_html(url):
    request = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return request.read()

def get_img(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    img_box = []
    imgs = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'pthumb')

    for img in imgs:
        img_box.append(get_domain(BASE_URL) + img.img['src'])

    for img in img_box:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, os.path.basename(img))


def main():
    get_img(get_html('https://fachowiec.com/sklep/pl/products/index?Products_page=1&pageSize=15'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_img(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    img_box = []
    imgs = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'pthumb')

    for img in imgs:
        img_box.append(get_domain(BASE_URL) + img.img['src'])

    my_path = '/home/<username>/Desktop'  # use whatever path you like
    for img in img_box:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, os.path.join(my_path, os.path.basename(img)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the pathname in second parameter of  urllib.request.urlretrieve. Something like below:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, "PATH"+os.path.basename(img))
```

The second argument, if present, specifies the file location to copy to (if absent, the location will be a tempfile with a generated name).